# import vpython produces error: float division by zero

Tags: python, vpython

I work with Python 3.10.0. I installed vpython using pip, it was installed successfully.

Then when I just use:

```
from vpython import *

print('hello')
```

`hello` is printed, and after that I get the following Error:

```
exit
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function Exit at 0x1095d4ee0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vpython/vpython.py", line 22, in Exit
    a = 1.0/zero
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

What does this mean? What can I do?

Comment: The code causing this exception was added to vpython [here](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter/commit/5051943529c88638893b7653c527e7ce56504ab3). I have no idea how this is supposed to make sense.

Comment: Any idea what can I do?

Comment: That statement (a = 1.0/zero) is inside a function named "exit" which facilitates killing a running VPython program in some situations. When I try your simple program, it works, whether starting from IDLE or from a terminal or in a Jupyter notebook. How are you launching the program? On what platform? With what browser?

Comment: I work with visual studio code , run it the terminal from visual , Python 3.10.0 63-bit  (3.10.0: pyenv) on mac with Monterey OS

Comment: Ah, now I see. In the particular case of running from a terminal, you need to add the following to the end of your program:
while True:
    rate(60)
In other environments this ending loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

`vpython 7.6.4`
throws the ZerodivisionError

but installing the version of 7.6.1 will resolve this issue.
`pip install vpython==7.6.1`

Comment: At exit, using Python 3.10.7 and vpython 7.6.1 I got: _File "c:\py_scripts\charged_rod_model.py", line 8, in <module>
    from vpython import vector
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\vpython\__init__.py", _line 25, in <module>
    raise Exception(s)
Exception: The non-notebook version of vpython requires Python 3.5 or later.
vpython does work on Python 2.7 and 3.4 in the Jupyter notebook environment._

Only installing `pip install vpython==7.6.3` worked for me.