# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero in vpython

Tags: vpython

I'm starting in python and just install vpython and it just doesn't work, even with the most simple code it prints:

```
exit
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function Exit at 0x7e245317be20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juancho/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vpython/vpython.py", line 22, in Exit
    a = 1.0/zero
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

It would really help me if someone knows how to fix that, bc a tried some solutions i found on blogs, but none worked, it keeps printing that. thanks

It would really help me if someone knows how to fix that, bc a tried some solutions i found on blogs, but none worked, it keeps printing that. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import vpython produces error: float division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083857/import-vpython-produces-error-float-division-by-zero)